# How to remove duplicate solutions without considering the numbers?

Tags: python, duplicates

I have this DataFrame

```
    m1  m2  m3  m4  m5
1   2   3   1   3   1
2   2   2   1   3   3
3   2   2   1   3   1
4   1   3   2   3   2
5   1   1   2   3   3
6   1   1   2   3   2
7   1   1   3   2   3
8   1   2   3   2   3
9   1   1   3   2   2
10  3   3   1   2   1
11  3   3   1   2   2
12  3   2   1   2   1
13  3   3   2   1   1
14  3   3   2   1   2
15  3   1   2   1   2
16  2   2   3   1   1
17  2   2   3   1   3
18  2   1   3   1   3
```

and I am trying to remove all duplicate solutions (each row is a solution). Duplicate solution means elements in the same position/column can not be the same.

Take row1=(2,3,1,3,1) row18=(2,1,3,1,3) as an instance, you can simply change 3->1 1->3 in `row1` to get `row18`

Applying this rule to the whole DataFrame, we can get the final result (manually)

```
    m1  m2  m3  m4  m5
1   2   3   1   3   1
2   2   2   1   3   3
3   2   2   1   3   1
```

Comment: I would do this processing BEFORE converting to pandas.  You're going to have to sort each row, then sort the set of rows.  At that point, the duplicates will all be gathered together and will be easy to spot.  THEN you can create a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you so much. While I got this DataFrame from a "black box" and it uses another language, I can not sort it before "converting to pandas".